# Фраза «…глазами, и, откуда бы…» — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В одном из изданий романа П. Валё «Гибель 31-го отдела» написано так: «Там был расположен Дом. Он и без того принадлежал к числу самых высоких в стране, а благодаря своему положению просматривался из любой части города. Он всегда был перед глазами, и, откуда бы человек ни ехал, Дом виднелся в конце его пути».
В другом издании запятая отсутствует в последнем предложении после «и»: «Он всегда был перед глазами, и откуда бы человек ни ехал, Дом виднелся в конце его пути».
Какой же вариант верен?
Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: Вы ведь говорите о разных переводах, верно? И в варианте без запятой приводите цитату с купюрами, да?

Comment: Нет, это две редакции одного и того же перевода - Софьи Фридлянд (другого перевода этой книги я не знаю). Оба варианта одинаковы по объему.

Comment: Тогда прошу извинить. Я ориентировался на поиск по гуглокнигам, который находит только один вариант без запятой в старом журнале, но там текст несколько другой (и он мне нравится больше, если судить по отрывкам). (Я также считаю, что без запятой лучше).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта допустимы. В первом случае корректор, видимо, руководствовался правилами пунктуации при соседстве сочинительного и подчинительного союзов: если возможно убрать придаточное, ставим между ними запятую. Структура позволяет убрать - поставили запятую.

Второй корректор рассудил по-другому: структура позволяет убрать, но смысл получается неясным: *Он всегда был перед глазами, и  Дом виднелся в конце его пути*. Неясно, в конце чьего пути.  Следовательно, здесь союз И относится не к главному предложению, а ко всему СПП: *Он всегда был перед глазами, и ( откуда бы человек ни ехал, Дом виднелся в конце его пути).*

У Розенталя есть похожие случаи: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140

Мне кажется более верным второй вариант, без запятой.